# how to get custom session in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, session, customer-session, checkoutsession, cm-redissession

I have tried this but this is giving empty log file.
What should I do to get output for this:

```
  public function isAdmin() {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream( BP . '/var/log/myfile.log' );
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter( $writer );
        $this->_coreSession->start();
        $logger->info( 'aaaa', $this->_coreSession->getMessage() );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use class `Magento\Customer\Model\Session` which will give you customer session object.

**For example:**

```
protected $customerSession;

public function _construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    ...
}
public function getName()  {
  return $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
}
```

In above example, you will get customer's name from customer session if you can `getName()` function.

Now, to get a custom session value, you must set it first (if it is not already set somewhere else). Here is how you can set it.

```
$testValue = 'this is test';
$this->customerSession->setTestValue($testValue);
```

Now, you have a custom session value available in customer session. You can get this value from your module using below code:

```
$testValue = $this->customerSession->getTestValue();
```

Comment: but i need admin session on frontend customlly

Comment: I have also added code on how to set/get custom value on customer session.